# JS function hook

Tags: javascript, function, events, hook, greasemonkey

Working in Greasemonkey script.
HTML page contains JS script with some function. I want know event (when) this function executed (done/return).

This code looks like work (Proxy for setPointer function):

```js
setPointer = new Proxy(setPointer, {
    apply: function(method, context, args) {
        alert("setPointer was invoked");
        method();
    }
});
```

But it's NOT works from Greasemonkey script. Only if I put it directly into HTML after setPointer function.

Comment: Either use `@grant none` or [How to access \`window\` (Target page) objects when @grant values are set?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25778469)